# Synergy 1.4.10 :unrecognised client name "APNANLL3M4335", check server config

Tags: synergy

Windows 7 links to Windows XP, use Windows 7 as a server. But I can't connect them.

Client log says

```
"server regused client with our name". 
server:"unrecognised client name ******, check server config".
```

What's wrong here

Comment: Oh my giddy aunt, this has wasted so much of my time, I 'nearly' asked for a refund. A simple setup guide on app startup is essential, unless it just works like Sharemouse (but costs more - yes im tight).

Answer (score 37):

Looks like you haven't added the client name to the server config.

[From Synergy user guide:](https://symless.com/help/articles/s1-getting-started)

> Windows
>
> On Windows run synergy by double clicking on the synergy file. This
>   brings up a dialog. Configure the server:
>
> - Click the Share this computer's keyboard and mouse (server) radio button
> - Click the Screens & Links Configure... button
> - Click the + button to add the server to the Screens list
>
>   - Enter the name of server (the computer's name is the recommended name)
>   - Optionally enter other names the server is known by
>   - Click OK
> - Use the + button to add your other computers
>
>   - Using a computer's name as its screen name is recommended
>   - Choose desired screen options on the Add Screen dialog
> - Use the controls under Links to link screens together
> - Click (once) on the server's name in the Screens list
>
>   - Choose the screen to the left of the server; use --- if there is no screen to the left of the server
>   - Choose the screens to the right, above and below the server
>   - Repeat the above steps for all the other screens
>   - Click OK to close the Screens & Links dialog
> - Use Options... to set desired options
> - If the server's screen name is not the server's computer name:
>
>   - Click Advanced...
>   - Enter the server's screen name next to Screen Name
>   - Click OK

Comment: now it works for me too!

Comment: I had to add my other computer now it is recognized and connects! but nothing happens, I cant find a single way to make the mouse move on the other computer, why that is not easy?

Comment: On a Linux server, I had to restart the Synergy server for the changes to take effect.  Then, everything worked.

Comment: Mac server also requires a restart.

Comment: with windows 7 server, mac client, I got this error when the mac tried to connect. I fixed it by installing bonjour on my windows computer. I think synergy tried to install it for me, but it failed, so I had to download manually from apple.

Comment: On Win7 64 (server) had to set it up as per @RATHI's answer below and then click Apply.

Comment: Our hostnames were super simple: `mike` and `kate`. Adding them wasn't enough. Even restarting the server didn't help. I had to add an _alias_ to the server configuration (on `mike`) for the client computer (`kate`) where the alias was the client IP (found that using `ip addr --list`).

Answer (score 31):

I too spend some time in this. The button for this is not that obvious. it looks like a icon rather that a button. Drag this button to the grid to add new screen[image]

Use this monitor type icon to add (by dragging) one more monitor to your server setup.
DO not use the special character in its name.

Comment: Special characters = a hyphen too. I looked all over for the plus sign and couldn't find this. Thanks!

Comment: dragging was so non obvious.

Comment: On Win7 64 (server) had to set it up as per answer but then also click Apply (on the main window) before it took effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but on Mac. I added the computer using the icon button shown @Satyha and added the name and alias.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please don't post an answer to confirm that another answer worked.  The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question, and each answer should contribute another solution.  The way to indicate that an answer was useful is to invest a little time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://superuser.com/help/privileges) to upvote answers you like.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had problem with that and spent quite much time to find out the problem. It seemed that you have to add that client (user) in “ALLOWED” list.

(source: https://puvox.software/blog/solution-synergy-shows-warning-error-unrecognised-client-name/ )

Comment: Your link is not broken...

Comment: @AlexisWilke I've put another source, check that works